# Classloader Filtering

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic-10.x, java-ee-5

I have asked a related question before - but this is not exactly the same. I was told earlier not to ask additional questions in the same thread if the issue is a bit different. So I am posting this new question. Pls let me know if I shouldn't.

I have a web-application (war file). Jar pertaining to apache-commons-lang is added in WEB-INF lib along with other jar file. However an older version of jar pertaining to apache-commons-lang is also present in system library and when deployed the jar file in system classpath takes precedence and I am getting "classnotfound" error. prefer-web-inf-classes has to be specified for the classes specified in WEB-INF to take precedence over classes present in the System Classloader.However I would like only this specific jar to take precedence over system classloader. I was advised to use "Filtering Classloaders" in weblogic when I had posted a similar issue. That solution works great when I have an ear. However I won't be able to add weblogic-application.xml in war file and I am not able to make use of this classloader filtering concept. Is there a way out? Thanks.

Comment: If it is not possible to do it via configuration , is there a possibility of me writing some code to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with WebLogic but if you know how the newer jar is being used and the entry into that code is as simple as instantiating a class and executing one start-up method, you might get away with a customized classloader?
See example at http://tshrestha.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-custom-classloader.html

But I admit, that some WebLogic guru out there knows how you can achieve this with some configuration of WebLogic itself.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues pointed out that having the relevant packages specified in weblogic.xml would solve the issue. Yet to try it out though.

```
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>javax.faces.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.faces.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.xml.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.xerces.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no weblogic guru but i see two ways (haven't tried this but just guessing)

1)keep only 'prefer-web-inf-classes' required jars in WEB-INF and move the rest to a different location and point them in MANIFEST.MF of war

2)bundle that war in a blank ear and specify all jars in MANIFEST.MF of the ear and specify the preference class  in weblogic-application.xml . The idea is to make war and ear part of the same application so that the web app can use same class loader (instead of using 'prefer-web-inf-classes' )

EDIT:
For the first point i have verified that weblogic ignores the Manifest file of war file. So first sol doesn't work. Also about the second sol if there are no ejbs present in ear weblogic blindly ignores Manifest of ear. So you have to move the libraries of WAR to either APP-INF\lib or simply lib dir of ear and specify the  preference package apache-commons-lang in weblogic-application.xml
Anyways dont think this is an efficeint solution (esp when you do not want to create an ear just for the sake of it)

Answer (score 0):

Vicky, i had the same issue as yours. The solution that worked for me is creating a **/lib** folder under the domain(some of this is in the weblogic documentation), adding any 3rd party JARs that you need to override and then specifying that library in the **PRE_CLASSPATH** variable in the **startWeblogic.cmd** file. 
In my case, weblogic had an older version of commons-lang and this was causing a conflict.
Since i didn't have a EAR deployment, the weblogic-application.xml solution was a no go.
After i added the following to my pre_classpath - 
set PRE_CLASSPATH=%PRE_CLASSPATH%;%DOMAIN_HOME%/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar;

my problem was resolved.

Comment: Thanks Daranha , this was one of the solutions that we used. But we didn't want to define it in the pre_classpath variable as it applies to all application displayed in the weblogic app server.